# How do I push script file into LABjs loading queue?

Tags: javascript, labjs

I am currently using LABjs to defer loading of scripts and in sub pages I am pushing into the queue for inline script like so.

```
<script> var _loadingQueue = [];</script>
<script>
     _loadingQueue.push(function(){
        var scheduledPmtData = {'PaymentCount' : 0};
     ...snip...
    });
</script>
```

then inside my main `$LAB` I do

```
    if( typeof( window[ '_loadingQueue' ]) !== "undefined"){
    for(var i=0,len=_loadingQueue.length; i<len; i++){
        $LoadDefer = $LoadDefer.wait(_loadingQueue[i]);
    }
}
```

My inline script has come to the point that I want to put it in an external JS file. How do I keep the same type of loading but as a script file not inline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did to get it working. If it can be refactored, please let me know.

Added another var 
`<script> var _loadingQueueScript = [];</script>`

Then where the inline code was, I did

```
<script>
  _loadingQueueScript = "/assets/scripts/source/addevent.js";
</script>
```

Then under my previous `$LoadDefer.wait()` I added

```
if( typeof( window[ '_loadingQueueScript' ]) !== "undefined"){
    $LoadDefer = $LoadDefer.script(_loadingQueueScript);
}
```